About the use of Bounties?
Shouldnt people use more their reputation points for Bounties?
and is there some statistics available about this vs other stackexchange sites?

Hard to say that they should, but the use of bounty is documented in the faq:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty
In general you would institute a bounty when you aren't getting answers, or you are getting inadequate answers.
As far as use on the network, it scales with traffic; you can browse around and check the homepage of a few sites in the Stack Exchange network:
http://stackexchange.com/sites
... and look for the Featured tab; if there are no bountied questions, this tab will not be present at all. But if it is, there will be a small number counting the # of bountied questions at the moment.

In the financial world, people work with bonuses. I have the feeling that people do not use this website because they do not have enough incentive to answer the questions.

@rock reputation score serves that function.

@RockScience if that were really true, then we wouldn't see such large communities over at Wilmott, NuclearPhynance, etc.  IMHO, we will see more bounties once people have more reputation to spare.

I'm not sure bounties would work for a Quant SE. For programming, you get a simple question-answer form, and to get an answer to a difficult question, you pay with rep points. On Quant SE, I'm not sure the same would work, mainly because questions are a lot more subjective.

I wouldn't despair of the potential of bounties here quite yet.  There's no lack of objective questions here.  Also, sometimes all one is looking for is a definitive and well-written reference on a topic, and it may be valuable to set a bounty to motivate people to help the questioner find those references.
